# UICollectionView and Custom Height

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

i'm using a uiviewcontroller with inside a uicollectionvieww, and i searched on internet how i can customize the height of my total uicollectionview.
For now i setup the uicollectionview with a height >= 1 (i'm using autolayout)
Then in my .m file i tried with:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(160, 160)];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
[flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0];
[flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0];
NSInteger itemCount = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, 160 * itemCount)];
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
NSLog(@"%f", self.collectionView.frame.size.height);
```

But in NSLog still show me the height to 1...how i can do for setup the height of my uicollectionview to a custom height(that is based on element in a section * 160).
Any suggest ? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Where i create the cells:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    GalleryCell *cell = (GalleryCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GalleryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSDictionary *photo = [self.beachImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [photo objectForKey:@"original_url"]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar-placeholder.png"]];


    return cell;

}
```

**EDIT:**
Maybe the problem is that i use autolayout ?
Here my constraints: http://cl.ly/image/2l0M432w0U1V
**EDIT:**
I tried with adding constraint by code:

```
[self.collectionView removeConstraints:self.collectionView.constraints];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1  constant:320];
    [self.collectionView addConstraints:@[con1]];
```

But not show my cells...

Comment: You never change the height of the `collectionView`.  You just change the layout.

Comment: I tried with self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(self.collectionView.frame.origin.x, self.collectionView.frame.origin.y, self.collectionView.frame.size.width, 160 * itemCount); but anyway not show me the collectionView, that remain to 1px.

Comment: how do you create your collectionView?  Show the code where you initialize it.  You should definitely delete the height constraints and the Bottom Space to superview 313 constraints.  If you want to adjust the height then do not put any constraints on it.